# I'm having trouble with axios get and post requests in real host

Tags: vue.js

When I'm on the local server localhost:8080 in vue project everything is great, but when I deploy the project to my real host I get the problem

```
mounted(){
        axios.get('http://localhost/online-store/src/database_api/Admin/recent_product.php')
        .then((res) => {
            this.products= res.data
            console.log(res.data)
        })
    },
```

Comment: `http://localhost/online-store/src/database_api/Admin/recent_product.php` is a local address, it is in your computer for development. you need the public address of this service api in deployment.

Answer (score 0):

configure your axios in main.js (entry point )

```
axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL
})
```

Then directly call api ..it will append base url based on your env parameter

```
 axios('/online-store/src/database_api/Admin/recent_product.php')
```

Note : Don't forget to add .env as per environment